# How to stop phone from downloading a system update?

Tags: update

My lumia 535 has started to download a system update by mistake. How do I stop the download? There's no option to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't test this since I don't have an update available, but I think you should be able to disable your cellular data (and get off Wi-Fi) and wait until the update fails. Then don't retry.